# Json API Response is not appending in the li attribute

Tags: jquery, json, api, asp.net-ajax

I want to show Menu  from API using ul and li but ajax response is not appending in the li. Kindly help me out.

Here is My HtML

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <ul><li id="results"></li></ul>
</div>
```

Here is My Script.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://any-url",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "ProjectId": "1" }),
        success: function (response) {
            var title = +response.ParentList;
            console.log(response);
            $.each(response, function () {

                $("#results").append(title.Name);
            })

        },
        error: function (status)
        {
            console.log(status.statusText);

        }
    });
</script>
```

And this is Ajax response in my console window.

```
Object {Message: "Successfully", Status: "OK", Parentlist: Array(10)}
Message:"Successfully"
Parentlist:Array(10)
0:Object
1:Object

Parentlist:Array(10)
 0:Object
  Child:Array(0)
  DisplayOrder:"-8"
  Id:"1012"
  Name:"Mysorie Chif
```

Comment: what do you see in console?

Comment: Why do you use `=+` in `var title = +response.ParentList;`

Comment: Could you add the response from `console.log(response)`

Comment: @Carsten Lovbo Andersen in console it shows the json object but it is not appending in li

Comment: @SaqibMajeed Yes I know that it would show a JSON object, but I'm not sure you're appending it correctly according to your JSON. That's why I'm asking you to include the result from the console.log in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 success: function (response) {
        $.each(response.ParentList, function () {
            $("#demo ul").append('<li>'+this.Name+'</li>');
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
    <ul><li class="results"></li></ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://any-url",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "ProjectId": "1" }),
        success: function (response) {
            var title = +response.ParentList;
            console.log(response);
            $.each(response, function () {

                $("#demo ul").append(title.Name);
            })

        },
        error: function (status)
        {
            console.log(status.statusText);

        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What did you change? It is always a good idea to include some words about the answer you provide

Comment: $("#demo ul").append(title.Name); You append the code in the li tag. But we want it in the ul tag and repeat the li.

Comment: Would `title.Name` in this case not show the same Name in every `each` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your ajax call is returning an array (more information on that could be welcomed).

Here is how to iterate on response items and append a new LI for each:

```
function onSuccess(response){
  $.each(response, function (index, item) {
    $("#resultRoot").append('<li>'+item.Name+'</li>');
  })
}
```

For that to work, you need to point to the UL tag (not the LI):

```
<div id="demo">
    <ul id="resultRoot"></ul>
</div>
```

And I leave the Ajax as is, just calling the onSuccess function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://any-url",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "ProjectId": "1" }),
    success: onSuccess,
    error: function (status)
    {
        console.log(status.statusText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this line `$("#demo ul").append('<li>' + this.ParentList.Name + '</li>');`

This will `append` a `li` and by using `this.ParentList.name` you should get the name value of the current `response`

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://any-url",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "ProjectId": "1"
  }),
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $.each(response, function() {

      $("#demo ul").append('<li>' + this.ParentList.Name + '</li>');
    })

  },
  error: function(status) {
    console.log(status.statusText);

  }
});
```